# How to db_insert into users?

Tags: database

I'm inserting new users into tables users (using a webservice that insert), but how to make `uid` being automatically inserted and it would be always the next value of the current maximal value on table users (and auto-increment too) ?

Thank you

Answer (score 7):

The `users` table doesn't have an auto-increment constraint on the primary key (or any field).

The recommended way to add users is using the API ([`user_save()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_save/7) etc), that will handle the ID for you.

Failing that, just query for the maximum ID in the table before you perform the insert; after the first insert, assuming you have exclusivity on this database while you're developing, you can maintain the increment in your code (no need to check the table each time).

Drupal does exactly the same thing in `user_save()`:

```
$account->uid = db_next_id(db_query('SELECT MAX(uid) FROM {users}')->fetchField());
```

Comment: Hi @Clive, thank you for your helpful answer ,as always, I didn't mentioned in my question that i've tested inserting using max + 1 in another query that fetch users etc.. So i'll keep it right now because as you said user_save do the same, so thank you

Comment: Sorry for off-topic, but what may be purpose of avoiding autoincrement?

Comment: Because of the anonymous user @ar7max, that needs an ID of `0`, so auto-increment isn't an option

Comment: But we still can create user, change id to 0 and reset autoincrement counter O.o

Comment: Can do, but one might consider that to be doing things the wrong way round. There may be other reasons I'm not aware of/have forgotten, but that's the one that sticks out in memory

Comment: I wonder if there are some if(userId) checks in code. Searched a little, but drupal inserts zero id manually on install :/

Comment: Found https://www.drupal.org/node/356074#comment-1819516

Comment: @Clive, i'm facing a new issue (using user_save()) in past days , i was creating new users , ones from drupal "create new user" and others from a mobile app (using services) the users added using the app were inserted by a custom query db_merge (fetching users and looking for max(uid), make max + 1 and putting it for the new user) it was always uid = 24 or 25...ect but in the other hand, i was adding users via drupal and uids were in interval 80,81..ect if i delete users (with uids 80s) and insert new with app, it's always showing message : duplicated 25 uid (for example)

Comment: @Clive even if the last user in users table is uid = 24 (after deleting all users and keeping last : 24). the probleme is the error message is shown but the user is added normally. and if i add a new user using drupal (user_save) it will not take uid = 26 but 82 for example

Comment: Mitch, as was described via link above its a problem of drupal. It uses sequences instead of auto incrementing

Comment: @ar7max yes i see. but how do user_save retrieve uids that are actually deleted. is there another table where there is uids ?

Comment: That's because in that example there's another record in there with an ID of 81. So the next available ID is 82. You would see identical behaviour if the DBMS was handling the auto-increment - they don't try to fill in gaps, they just keep going up from the highest available number (or in the case of a DB-side auto-increment, the current seed). @ar7max I wouldn't call it a problem, personally, it was a decision taken to minimise other issues related to the users table

Answer (score 3):

Use
[user_save()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_save/7)

and try to avoid direct db_insert for new user creation. With direct db_insert you cut off the whole functionality of Drupal and other Modules

Answer (score 2):

you can enter new user using [user_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/user_save/5)

```
$account = (object) array ();
$options['name'] = $username;
$options['mail'] = $email;
$options['pass'] = md5($passwd);
$result = user_save($account, $options);
if ($result === FALSE) {
   //take some action
} else {
   //$result is the loaded user object
}
```

Comment: That snippet is for VERY OLD Drupal 5